# Minkowski/canonical volume vs Lesbegue

Tags: number-theory

In Neukirch (Algebraic Number Theory) on page 31 he says the canonical (Minkowski) metric differs from the Lesbegue metric by:
$$ Vol_{canonical}(X) = 2^s Vol_{Lesbegue}(f(X)).$$
Here $X$ is a complete lattice in Minkowski space, $K_{\mathbb R}$ and $f(X)$ its image in $\mathbb R^{r + 2s}$ under the map $f(z_\tau) = x_\tau$ where $x_\tau = z_\tau$ for all real $\tau$ and $x_\tau = Re(z_\tau)$, $x_\overline{\tau} = Im(z_\tau)$ at complex $\tau$. The canonical/minkowski measure is induced by the inner product $<x, y > = \sum \alpha_\tau x_\tau y_\tau$ where $\alpha_\tau = 1$ at the $r$ real $\tau$ and $2$ at the $2s$ complex $\tau$. The Lesbegue metric is of course induced by the usual inner product $< x, y > = \sum x_i y_i$.

My question is how can I see this? I've tried working from the determinant definition of volume but can't see how to pull out the $2^s$. If it helps:

$$ Vol(X) = |det(A)| = |det(<v_i, v_j>)|^{1/2}$$
where $A$ is the matrix with basis vectors of the lattice as its columns and the $v_i$ are the basis vectors themselves.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:number-theory]?  This looks like differential or Riemannian geometry to me.  Or maybe symplectic geometry?  These are not parts of mathematics with which I am overly familiar, but number theory seems quite inappropriate here...

Comment: @Xander Henderson: I too am a bit confused, because when one says "Minkowski metric" and "Minkowski space", I would have thought the notion was Minkowski space-time in relativity theory. Perhaps this is a generalization of that notion used in algebraic number theory, or at least used in Neukirch's book, but since Neukirch wrote several books and we aren't told which book it is, as written this question seems unnecessarily specifically targeted to the 3 people in Stack Exchange who could pick up on the context (intended as hyperbole, of course), none of whom probably even saw the question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Here Minkoswski space is that one obtained from real and complex embeddings of a number field. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_bound

Comment: @XanderHenderson, apologies for being unclear. This is from Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory. He builds up Minkowski theory in order to prove the class number is finite, which is why I initially filed this under number theory. I don't know much about Riemannian or sympletic geometry but would be happy to add / change the tag if others are more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, the trick is to use the $|det(A)|$ definition of the volume (the definition in terms of the inner product doesn't make much sense since the inner product in $K_\mathbb{R}$ is different - Edit: actually see reuns answer below). Then you can see what happens to $A$ as you go from $X$ to $f(X)$: to get the resulting matrix you divide $s$ of the columns by $2$ (you also need to add some of the columns together and divide by $i$ but this doesn't effect $|det(A)|$.

Answer (score 1):

One inner product is obtained from the other by multiplying the $x_i$ of the complex embeddings by $\sqrt{2}$, ie.  $$ <x,y>_{canonical} \ =\ < Dx,Dy>_{Lebesgue}$$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with r ones and 2s $\ \sqrt{2}$,

then $\det(D) = \sqrt{2}^{2s} =2^s$, thus it sends a lattice of covolume $v$ to a lattice of covolume $2^s v$.